# SIGSEGV error JDK18, how to debug core dump

Tags: java, ubuntu, minecraft

I am editing this question to better fit the rules. I am consistently getting a SIGSEGV error with libjvm(?). I was told it would be fixed in JDK18, but the issue persists.

The current error I receive is;

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4628ef1f4b, pid=95484, tid=95504
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (18.0.2+9) (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-222.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 2868 c2 java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode()I java.base@18.0.2-ea (45 bytes) @ 0x00007f4628ef1f4b [0x00007f4628ef1ae0+0x000000000000046b]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /opt/minecraft/server/core.95484)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xms1024M -Xmx10G Minecraft_Server_1.20.jar nogui

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 cores, 62G, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
...cont
```

**My question is;**

How would I diagnose why the bug is occurring? Believe it is likely a conflicting dependency, but I do not know where to look. There is no file at `/opt/minecraft/server/core.95484`, and I do not understand how to debug the core dump I generated at `/var/crash`.

What I have tried;

- running  gdb /`cat ExecutablePath` CoreDump
- 
- 

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bug in JDK https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274053. Apparently fixed in latest builds of JDK 18 though I could not find in which one exactly.